# POST Request not working, but GET works an lokal all works

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, request

I am trying to do a POST request with AJAX.
This Site http://www.learn-it-up.de/sap-kurse/ do a AJAX POST to http://www.learn-it-up.de/wp-content/themes/lms/framework/courses_utils.php but it returns a 403 forbidden.

When I call the site http://www.learn-it-up.de/wp-content/themes/lms/framework/courses_utils.php direkt in brwoser (GET) it works! So only POST is not working.

When I try this all on my localhost it works too!
So what configurations can I change to get this work?

I can not post the AJAX Request because it is not allowed to publish the code, but as I sag on localhost it is working.

By the way I am using Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the server configuration is rejecting the POST http method. Also maybe you have some mod_rewrite (I'm assuming apache) rules in the server that could be redirecting your post someplace else.

Moreover, the infrastructure or the configuration of both the server and the wordpress instance you are testing to could be entirely different from your environment, maybe you have an nginx in between or some other component that could be interfering, etc.

Compare configurations and infrastructure between your local environment and the server and you will most likely find the answer.